# I am creating a form using React and getting this error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native

This is the error I am getting:

```
./src/App.js
  Line 26:10:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ";"

  24 |   }
  25 | }
> 26 | render() {
     |          ^
  27 |   const { characters } = this.state;
  28 | 
  29 |   return (
```

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Table from './Table'

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    characters: [
      {
        name: 'Charlie',
        job: 'Janitor',
      },
      {
        name: 'Mac',
        job: 'Bouncer',
      },
      {
        name: 'Dee',
        job: 'Aspring actress',
      },
      {
        name: 'Dennis',
        job: 'Bartender',
      },
    ],
  }
}
render() {
  const { characters } = this.state;

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Table characterData={characters} removeCharacter={this.removeCharacter} />
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: add your full App.js file code

Comment: import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Table from './Table'

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    characters: [
      {
        name: 'Charlie',
        job: 'Janitor',
      },
      {
        name: 'Mac',
        job: 'Bouncer',
      },
      {
        name: 'Dee',
        job: 'Aspring actress',
      },
      {
        name: 'Dennis',
        job: 'Bartender',
      },
    ],
  }
}

Comment: render() {
  const { characters } = this.state;

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Table characterData={characters} removeCharacter={this.removeCharacter} />
    </div>
  )
}

export default App

Answer (score 2):

You are adding curly brackets

> "{"

at wrongs places

Make it like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Table from './Table'

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    characters: [
      {
        name: 'Charlie',
        job: 'Janitor',
      },
      {
        name: 'Mac',
        job: 'Bouncer',
      },
      {
        name: 'Dee',
        job: 'Aspring actress',
      },
      {
        name: 'Dennis',
        job: 'Bartender',
      },
    ],
  }
render() {
  const { characters } = this.state;

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Table characterData={characters} removeCharacter={this.removeCharacter} />
    </div>
  )
}
}
export default App;
```

Basically your render function is outside of your App class so that is why your code is not working.

Comment: ./src/index.js
Attempted import error: './App.js' does not contain a default export (imported as 'App').

Comment: at the end of file add: export default App;

Comment: ./src/index.js
Attempted import error: './App.js' does not contain a default export (imported as 'App').         still not getting the result help please

Comment: I have changed my code in the answer. Copy paste it again from the answer. It should work.

Answer (score 1):

Please Put your render() method inside your App class